# Creating an Array clone with spread operator, but it still has reference to original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have these few lines of code:

```
  console.log(...cells);

  let testCells = [...cells];
  testCells[index].shape = selectedShape;
  testCells[index].player = player;

  console.log(...cells);
```

The interesting thing is that it is `console.log()`ing back the following.

[image]

I don't quite get it, why does `cells` change? There is no other part of the code that could interfere with `cells`. Any tips?

[Full code available here.](https://codepen.io/IDONNHAVE/details/qBpQZad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like even though you're spreading all the objects into the new array, it is still a reference to the old objects. You can break the reference by using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to avoid any old unintended relationships.

```js
  const cells = [
    {shape: 0, player: 0},
    {shape: 0, player: 0},
    {shape: 0, player: 0},
    {shape: 0, player: 0},
    {shape: 0, player: 0},
    {shape: 0, player: 0},
    {shape: 0, player: 0},
    {shape: 0, player: 0},
    {shape: 0, player: 0},
  ];
  
  console.log(...cells);
  
  const breakRef = obj => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

  let testCells = breakRef(cells);
  testCells[0].shape = 1;
  testCells[0].player = 0;

  console.log(...cells);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it. Any idea why reference is not broken?

Comment: Just the way objects work in js, when you assign an object to a new variable it works as a reference. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) for more info :)

Comment: Thank you! I thought that the spread operator should break all references by itself, but I guess it doesn't. You really saved me from a few more hours of debugging!